# Using BlockingCollection with Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, producer-consumer

I have a process that does a bunch of document processing.  One of the tasks being performed is OCR, which is the slowest part of the process, so I decided to run that in another thread.

I decided the producer/consumer would work best because I will be adding document ids as each document is being processed (and there will be thousands of documents processed).

I also decided to use the Parallel.ForEach instead of kicking off many consumer threads because I figured the Parallel.ForEach will utilize the resources much better than I could do it on my own.

Another requirement is that I need to be able to cancel the process.

**Question:** Are my decision above sound decision (regarding using the BlockingCollection and Parallel.ForEach)?

**Review:** Is my code resilient?  Am I doing things correctly regarding handling the cancellation?

**Note:**  I have some questions within the code.

```
public class DocumentOcrQueue
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<int> _documentIds = new BlockingCollection<int>();
    private Task _consumer;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public void Add(int documentId)
    {
        _documentIds.Add(documentId);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Start the OCR Service.  Once the service has started it will start processing document Ids in the queue
    /// </summary>
    public void Start()
    {
        try
        // The token source for issuing the cancelation request.
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var cts = _cts;

        // Question:  I put the cancellation token as the parameter of the 
        //            Task.Run but I am not sure if this is needed.  
        //            Any advice on this?
        _consumer = Task.Run(() => OcrConsumer(cts.Token), cts.Token);
    }

    private void OcrConsumer(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var options = new ParallelOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount,
            CancellationToken = cancellationToken
        };

        try
        {
            // GetConsumingPartitioner is an extension method.  See class below.
            Parallel.ForEach(_documentIds.GetConsumingPartitioner(), options, id =>
            {
                options.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                PerformOcr(id);
            });
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            bool notCancelledExceptionOccurred = false;
            foreach (var ex in ae.InnerExceptions.Where(e => !(e is OperationCanceledException)))
            {
                notCancelledExceptionOccurred = true;
                // Log exception
            }

            if (notCancelledExceptionOccurred)
                throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log exception
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            _cts.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void PerformOcr(int documentId)
    {
        // Do OCR work here.
    }

    public void Stop(bool stopImmediately = false)
    {
        _documentIds.CompleteAdding();

        if (stopImmediately)
            _cts.Cancel();

        // Question
        // Does it matter if I use Task.WaitAll or _consumer.Wait()?
        // Is there an advantage of one over the other?
        Task.WaitAll(_consumer);
        // _consumer.Wait();
    }
}

// BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable and Parallel.ForEach can work against each other so found this sample code which solves this.
// http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx
static class BlockingCollectionExtention
{
    public static Partitioner<T> GetConsumingPartitioner<T>(this BlockingCollection<T> collection)
    {
        return new BlockingCollectionPartitioner<T>(collection);
    }

    private class BlockingCollectionPartitioner<T> : Partitioner<T>
    {
        private readonly BlockingCollection<T> _collection;

        internal BlockingCollectionPartitioner(
            BlockingCollection<T> collection)
        {
            if (collection == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collection));

            _collection = collection;
        }

        public override bool SupportsDynamicPartitions => true;

        public override IList<IEnumerator<T>> GetPartitions(int partitionCount)
        {
            if (partitionCount < 1)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(partitionCount));

            var dynamicPartitioner = GetDynamicPartitions();
            return Enumerable.Range(0, partitionCount).Select(_ => dynamicPartitioner.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
        }

        public override IEnumerable<T> GetDynamicPartitions()
        {
            return _collection.GetConsumingEnumerable();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Nothing prevents `Start` method from being called multiple times.
2. `Start` method code is broken
3. `Task.Run(…, token)` allows task cancellation before starting.
4. `Task.Wait()` is OK.
5. `DocumentOcrQueue` violates SRP. It does job management, error handling, and document OCR.
6. Also, running `LongTask` with `PreferFairness` option could be a way simpler – they worked out well for me in such kind of situation under a heavy load. Scheduler looks smart enough and basically has the same blocking queue inside.

I use the following class for such kind of things:

```
class TaskGroup : IDisposable
{
    public Task Run(Action<CancellationToken> action)
    {
        var task = new Task(() => action(Cts.Token), 
            Cts.Token, 
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);

        byte dummy;
        task.ContinueWith(t => Tasks.TryRemove(task, out dummy));
        task.ContinueWith(t => Error?.Invoke(this, t.Exception), 
            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted | TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled);

        Tasks.TryAdd(task, 0);
        task.Start();
        return task; 
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Cts.Cancel();
        Task.WhenAll(Tasks.Keys) // do not throw
            .ContinueWith(t => { }).Wait();
    }

    public event EventHandler<Exception> Error;
    CancellationTokenSource Cts { get; } = new CancellationTokenSource();
    ConcurrentDictionary<Task, byte> Tasks { get; } = new ConcurrentDictionary<Task, byte>();
}
```

It runs a bunch of tasks and allows to cancel them at once:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tg = new TaskGroup();
        tg.Error += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(e);
        tg.Run(ct => Ocr(ct, 1));
        tg.Run(ct => Ocr(ct, 2));
        tg.Run(ct => Ocr(ct, 3));

        Console.ReadLine();
        tg.Dispose();
    }

    static void Ocr(CancellationToken token, int id)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            Console.WriteLine($"{id}...");
    }
```

Comment: I will give this a try.  A couple questions.  It seems your implementation kicks off a different task for every document that needs to be OCR'ed.  Am I understanding this correctly?  If so, why do a `while` loop inside the OCR code?  It seems like (in your example) the `while` loop just keeps running the same code until someone presses Enter.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, please put your own code in OCR. The class above (TaskGroup) is OK to be used as it is. OCR is just a dummy thing to simulate real long running job. Do not forget to check the same way the cancelation token somewhere inside your OCR logic.

Comment: I get that part, I am just trying to understand if the expectation is that I should run one task for every document I will be doing OCR against or if I should run a small set of tasks and have each task run a subset of the total documents that need to be OCR'ed.  I will have thousands of documents being OCR'ed and it seems like kicking off thousands of threads is a bad idea, but I don't understand the underlying processes of the Task Scheduler so maybe kicking off thousands of threads is okay?

Comment: I was requesting hundreds of long running tasks at once to generate report pages - it was actually executing around 15 of them on my server - it actually creates a pool of jobs to process when resources becomes available, `PreferFairness` option converts it to something like a queue. Feel free to invoke `TaskGroup.Run` whenever you have a document ID.

Comment: Then there is probably something with the OCR process that makes the TaskScheduler think the OCR process takes little resources because I requested 100 documents to be OCR'ed and the Task Scheduler ran all 100 of them at the same time.  Within 5 seconds I was getting exceptions occurring within my OCR process.  Is there a way you can set the maximum number of threads allowed to be executed at once?

Comment: You need to specify `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness` in the `Task` ctor. It should help - see `TaskGroup` above.

Comment: I did that.  Using your routine exactly as specified above.  Probably something about the OCR process.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GeneS It sounds funny, but could you please remove `LongRunning` task keeping `PreferFairness`? I checked the doc and ran the test - it will work. `DefaultScheduler` uses `LongRunning` as an invitation to create a new dedicated thread. I have tried `DefaultScheduler` without it - I have no more than 8 intensive tasks on a  8 threaded cpu.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41173/discussion-between-gene-s-and-dmitry-nogin).